# running Jython code from a Python application

Tags: python, django, jython

So I know Jython code *IS* python code.. but I'm attempting to integrate a working jython script into a django application

I was expecting something like importing jython, or somehow invoking the jython interpreter from within a python script.

Comment: Assuming your code is actually compatible, you can just "import myjythonscript" or if you are just trying to execute it, you could do exec(open('myjythonscript.py').read())... or just copy/paste it...

Comment: [...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/jython/)

Comment: @orange that doesnt actually invoke it within a jython env... with a .py it will default to a python. @ Ignacio is there a problem? Its not as simple as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen django-jython? See http://code.google.com/p/django-jython/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/jython/

If you use this project you get a Django environment on top of Jython in a Jython environment.

Comment: know of any hosts who will let me deploy this kind of stack?

Comment: @delinquentme: Have you tried searching on "java servlet hosting"?

Comment: the idea here is to run a small java servlet and throw whatever I need processed at it over some api?

Comment: It's not "some API", it's *Django*.